# Is there a reverse of split in maxima? A join function?

Tags: maxima

I'm searching for a function that is in a lot of other languages called `join`. It would act like the the reverse of `split`.

I would expect it to work that `str_join(split("1;2", ";"), ";")` would become `"1:2"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it exist, but you could define it like this:

```
str_join(list, delim) := block(
    if length(list) = 0 then return (""),
    lreduce(
        lambda(
            [p,c], 
            if not(stringp(p)) then p: string(p),
            if not(stringp(c)) then c: string(c),
            concat(p, delim, c)
        ), 
        list
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get the effect you want via the `~{` `~}` (iteration in output) construct in `printf`. Note also that I've used `~^` (escape from iteration) construct as well.

```
(%i5) printf (true, "~{~a~^:~}~%", [1,2,3,4]);
1:2:3:4
(%o5)                                false
```

`? printf` doesn't go into details. But output control operators for `printf` are borrowed directly from Common Lisp, so you can find the info at the CL Hyperspec. See: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm

EDIT: You can get a string as a return value (instead of printing to standard output) via `printf(false, ...)`.